# Scatter diagram: How can i replace my dots with diamonds (marker symbol)?

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

How can i change my dots to diamonds? Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar]
\addplot[
scatter,mark=*,only marks,
point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
]
table {
x y  myvalue
0.5 0.63    0.25
3.2 5.91    0.75
0.7 0.119   0.125
0.35    0.2 2
3.65    0.7 0.175
0.2 0.35    0.225
0.7 0.63    0.275
0.35    0.91    3
0.65    0.119   0.325
0.2 0.2 0.375
2.7 0.7 0.425
0.35    3.35    4
7.65    0.63    0.475
0.2 0.91    0.525
0.65    0.119   0.575
6.2 0.147   5
0.7 0.175   0.625
0.35    3.203   0.675
0.65    2.231   0.725
0.2 0.259   6
5.65    0.287   0.775
0.2 0.315   0.825
0.7 0.343   0.875
0.35    0.371   7
0.65    0.399   0.925
0.2 0.427   2
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mark=diamond` instead of `mark=*`, or `mark=diamond*` for filled diamonds.

See section **4.7.1 Markers** in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) for a complete list of available markers.